# FlexBox: How can i keep boxes fixed one below the other

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm trying to create a page using FlexBox so i can keep the main image always centered with the top logo and page. And add of "off-center" text, next to the left.

My problem now is that i cannot make each box (image+text) keep their place vertically, boxes float and they have different space between each other based on what i'm using to view (big screen, laptop).

Not an expert with FlexBox, can i do that?

And also, i want to add a bar after the third box, 100% width...but it's placing in the middle of the page, between the boxes.

Any help will be welcome and i'll keep learning :)

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner-container {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  display: flex;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.off-center {
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: bottom;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.center, .off-center {
  position: absolute;
}

.center img {width: 100%;}

.off-center h2 {font-size:12px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 400;text-transform: uppercase; color:black; display: block!important;margin: 0px;}
.off-center p {font-size: 20px; font-family:'aileronbold', sans-serif; display: block!important;margin: 0px;text-transform: none;}

.row.subscriptionBar {display:flex; background-color: black; display: block; padding:20px;}
.subscriptionBar h2 {color:white;}
.firstPart {display: }

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .off-center {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .off-center {
    margin-top: 105px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"><img src="https://www.oilandgasreinvented.com/img/logo-placeholder.svg" width="80px"></div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="center">
     <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt=""></div>
    <div class="off-center">
     <h2 class="">ArtistName 1</h2>
  <p>509476ZclHtqXy</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="center">
     <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt=""></div>
    <div class="off-center">
     <h2 class="">ArtistName 2</h2>
  <p>Title lala 1</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="center">
      <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt=""></div>
    <div class="off-center">
      <h2 class="">ArtistName 3 444</h2>
    <p>Title 093830</p></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: I'm adding what i'm suppose to do]

Comment: Your code looks really really close to what you're trying to achieve. Can you explain a little more what the actual issue is?

Comment: Sure, thank you. 

Issues:

1) Images/boxes are moving vertically, sometimes going over the logo at the top. I'm used to work with Bootstrap and CSS but with flexbox i don't know how to set boundaries. 

2) Same issue than previous item i think, but how can i set horizontal images and vertical images to keep the same proportions. Check example/wireframe attached on my post. Currently, vertical image overlap with the other boxes.

3) Horizontal bar: in the middle of the page, i want it after the third box.

Comment: I don't see any horizontal bar in your layout. Also, you may want to simplify the question by breaking down the problem a bit more. Maybe focus this question on one problem. Once that's taken care of, focus on the next in a new question. This will make the problems easier to understand and more appealing to contributors.

Comment: I think your layout would be a lot easier if you added `flex-direction: column;` to your container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

header{
  background: tomato;
}

section{
  display: flex
}
.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.main img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

.full-width {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main    { order: 2; flex: 3 0px; }
.aside { flex: 1 auto; }
.aside-1 { order: 1; background: gold; width: 10%} 
.aside-2 { order: 3; background: hotpink; position: relative; width: 10%}
.aside-2 > span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.vertical {
  width: 15%; /* Modify this value for different screen size*/
}
/* .full-width  { order: 4; } */
/*@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main    { flex: 3 0px; }
  .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
  .main    { order: 2; }
  .aside-2 { order: 3; }
  .footer  { order: 4; }
}*/
body {
  padding: 2em; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header><img src="https://www.oilandgasreinvented.com/img/logo-placeholder.svg" width="80px"></header>
    <section>
        <div class="main">
        <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt="">
        </div>
        <aside class="aside aside-1"></aside>
        <aside class="aside aside-2"><span>Aside Right</span></aside>
    </section>
        <section>
       <div class="main">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
       </div>
       <aside class="aside aside-1 vertical"></aside>
       <aside class="aside aside-2 vertical"><span>Aside Right</span></aside>
   </section>
    <section>
     <div class="main">
          <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt="">
        </div>
        <aside class="aside aside-1"></aside>
        <aside class="aside aside-2"><span>Aside Right</span></aside>
    </section>

   <section class="full-width">Full Width</section>
    <section>
        <div class="main">
        <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt="">
        </div>
        <aside class="aside aside-1"></aside>
        <aside class="aside aside-2"><span>Aside Right</span></aside>
    </section>
</div>
```

I'm just doing a quick sample because it's not clear on what you're looking for. If this is the direction you're hoping to move toward, then I may be able to assist further.

Comment: You're awesome, thanks! This is exactly what i needed. From what i see one of my main issues was the flexbox set up, you added orders to flexboxes and then inside each section you use positioning absolute to position the image+text and that made perfect sense.

I'll work on the media queries.

I only have one more question because i don't see that on this answer: If i put a vertical oriented image, will try to use 100% width. If you see the example attached, the diff between horizontal image and vertical. Currently when vertica, stretch the image to use 100% width.

Comment: Question: How dynamic is your page going to be? What are the ratio point that you are going use to set your images? or it will be completely static? If you don't want the image to use 100% width, then you can set it max-width: 100% instead of width:100%. If your page is going to be static then you may use the modification but it's not ideal, more like a temp fix to get an idea. If it's going to be dynamic then there are other ways to handle it. Let me know!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dynamic vs static....
What i don't want is to use 100% width for vertical images...because the vertical oriented image tries to use 100% of the width and it became larger than the horizontal one because is giving priority to keep 100% of the width and i don't want that...the vertical should show a "smaller" width, centered...check on my original post with the images, there's a vertical image.

I'll try with max-width, to see if that helps. 

Thanks!

Comment: Oh i think i understad...it will be fully static, it's a temp website and i can manage the updates through code.

Comment: I forgot to mention it but I updated the codes earlier, check it out if that's what you want

Comment: Thanks, yes, this helps me. I did the same thing as you and it worked (adding the vertical class and change the size), since it's a 100% static website and temporary, we can go to not so dynamic / nice options, but should works fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have a few too many things going on with your combination of flexbox and absolute positioning. Below is a version of your snippet with much of the unnecessary css commented out (so you can see exactly what it is) plus a couple of new additions.

Most important changes other than removing some of the absolute positioning are removing `flex-wrap` from your `.container` and adding `flex-direction: column` as well as matching the widths of `.center` and `.off-center` so you can use `position: absolute` on `.off-center` (good use of it in that case) along with `margin-left` equivalent to the width to ensure that it is positioned just to the right of your image container.

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;*/
}

.top {
  border: 1px solid white;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  height: 10%;
  /*align-self: flex-start;*/
  text-align: center;
}

.inner-container {
  border: 1px solid white;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  height: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.center {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  /*align-self: flex-end;*/
}

.off-center {
  position: absolute;
  /*vertical-align: bottom;*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: 50%;
}


/*.center, .off-center {
  position: absolute;
}*/

.center img {
  width: 100%;
}

.off-center h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  display: block!important;
  margin: 0px;
}

.off-center p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'aileronbold', sans-serif;
  display: block!important;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: none;
}

.row.subscriptionBar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.subscriptionBar h2 {
  color: white;
}

.firstPart {
  display:
}

/*@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .off-center {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .off-center {
      margin-top: 105px;
    }
  }*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"><img src="https://www.oilandgasreinvented.com/img/logo-placeholder.svg" width="80px"></div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="center">
      <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="off-center">
      <h2 class="">ArtistName 1</h2>
      <p>509476ZclHtqXy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="center">
      <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt=""></div>
    <div class="off-center">
      <h2 class="">ArtistName 2</h2>
      <p>Title lala 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="center">
      <img src="http://hdimages.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image1.gif" alt=""></div>
    <div class="off-center">
      <h2 class="">ArtistName 3 444</h2>
      <p>Title 093830</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is not working for me this because i'm still having issues with floating.  
I cannot upload how i'm seeing this but the boxes are separating from each other if you have a smaller desktop...

Comment: There must be some other css or a conflicting library that is causing your issue. The html and css in the answer snippet would not cause any separation between the images on different device sizes (you can expand the snippet to full page and then test various device widths in your browser to see what I am talking about). That said, it looks like you found what you needed in the other answer which is very nicely put together by @KendraChu.

Comment: Yes, great answer by @KendraChu. Now i just have some issues with image responsiveness...if i remove the `width:100%` from `.main img` i get what i need, which is keeping images ratios and proportions (a vertical image shuld not use the same amount of width as an horizontal one) BUT if i do that, image is not responsive.